# Webview not loading due to memory problem during editing

Tags: javascript, android

I had been using this [richeditor library](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android) to add some feature to my project. It is extending from a webview.

The webview is working well but with a problem.

1. Webview didn't load due to insufficient memory when the content is too much. Added the below to rich_editor.js and it load well in viewing (solved half). Unfortunately, **load by section didn't work during editing.** Once clicked on and try to edit, it still tried to load everything and failed.

   ```
   var chunkSize = 500; // Maximum chunk size (in characters)

   function loadNextSection() {
   if (currentSection < content.length) {
       var nextSection = content[currentSection];
       var remainingContent = nextSection;

   while (remainingContent.length > 0) {
       var chunk = remainingContent.slice(0, chunkSize);
       remainingContent = remainingContent.slice(chunkSize);
       document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML += chunk;
   }

   currentSection++;
   }
   }

   // Add a scroll event listener to detect when the user scrolls
   RE.editor.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   if (shouldLoadNextSection()) {
   loadNextSection();
   }
   });

   function shouldLoadNextSection() {
   var editor = RE.editor;
   return (editor.scrollTop + editor.clientHeight >= editor.scrollHeight);
   }

   // Initialize by loading the first section
   loadNextSection();
   //--rest of code --

   RE.editor.addEventListener("click", RE.enabledEditingItems);
   ```

Comment: So a couple things.  1, that's a dead project, it hasn't been updated in 2 years.  I wouldn't use it for anything.  2, I'd avoid using webviews for anything you can possibly avoid using them for.  They're slow, use a ton of memory, and have a variety of issues that need to be carefully managed.  They also don't have the same experience as a native EditText.  3, if you're having memory problems, the only answer is to use less memory somewhere in your app.  The problem may be in the native or js code, use a profiler to find it.  4, don't use multiple of these on a page, webview is expensive.

Comment: Basically using a webview for this is just about the worst idea for using a webview I've ever seen.  Find a real rich text library, or write your own.  This library should be nuked from orbit.

Comment: hahaha, i am just wanting to add some checkbox in edittext, and the chatgpt actually suggested I use webview due to edittext could not provide the same feature. I would try to use edittext + drawable then. Or let me know if you have some recommendations, library or workaround.I like your last line. XD